# How to set up a cronjob that accesses a website every 5 minutes

Tags: heroku, cron

I am hosting a site on ep.io and heroku. The way they work is that when your website isn't accesed for some amount of time, the server is 'shut off' only to be restarted when someone visits your domain. I noticed that this generally will take up to 15 seconds for the page to load.

To counter this problem I want to make a cron job on another hosting I have, that tries to access my ep.io/heroku webpage every 5 minutes for example. I however have no clue how this would work as I have never used cronjobs.

I think I should add something like this to the crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://myapp.heroku.com
```

Is this a valid crontab line? If not, how should it be?

**Answer:**

Ok, After some searching around I found a solution, I'll post it here so others can benefit.

Make a python script (e.g. acces_page.py) that loads a URL:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://myapp.heroku.com')
    print f.read(10)
```

Then upload it somewhere on your second, not heroku, server (/webapps/myapp/ for me) and add the following line to your crontab (`crontab -e`):

```
*/5 * * * * ~/webapps/myapp/access_page.py > $HOME/cron.log 2>&1
```

This will run the script every five minutes, accessing your webpage defined in your python script. To test if it works it will output the first 10 characters of the webpage in the file cron.log in your $HOME directory.

If it says something like access denied, chmod your .py file with `chmod +x access_page.py`.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This belongs on SuperUser. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: hum.. did you try this from your local?

Comment: How is this not a programming question? Honestly, I don't understand?

Comment: from FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" and "a specific programming problem" and "software tools commonly used by programmers"?

Answer (score 0):

add some thing to happen in your url page.
 in your example http://myapp.heroku.com/index.php file.

write in DB or a file will be better

Comment: Could you elaborate on why I should do this? It doesn't really matter what page I access on my domain, I just want some call so the server would go in standby mode, right?